# How to send a copy of a SQL Server 2008R2 database to someone off-site, for support purposes

Tags: sql-server

I need to send a copy of a SQL Server 2008R2 database to a technical support person outside our company.

We use Windows authentication, not SQL authentication on our databases.

How can I get a copy of this database to this person and she be able to access it?  Someone else sent them a copy and they said they "couldn't open" it.

I've created a "Copy-Only" backup of the database, but haven't sent it yet.  I have my doubts they would be able to open it without having access from our network login.

I would appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you in advance.

David

Comment: Side Note: I hope you are scrubbing the data before you are sending it to remove any [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data)? The last thing you want is that this 3rd party leaks your data either maliciously or accidentally. If you think that couldn't or won't happen think again, there are *many* data leaks that occur in this manner (data exposed by 3rd parties).

Comment: If your database backup is not encrypted then this 3rd party can restore it (assuming they have a matching or higher Sql Server instance that is running). As they (or someone they work with) have sys admin access to this instance they can access your database running on that instance post restore.

Comment: In addition to what @Igor said, keep in mind that database backups may contain *deleted* data, including old copies of rows that have since been modified, because they work by copying data pages regardless of what's in them, not by copying the logical row data. Securely scrubbing data is not trivial -- a reliable clean copy means creating a new database and selectively copying/transforming data from the original.

Comment: Oh.  Thank you for the cautions.  I did not know some of that.  This 3rd party is the designer of the database and supporting system whom we've asked to implement some additional features.  I know that does not negate the need to scrub the database.  Perhaps we should arrange for them to do "in place" updates on a backup database in our environment instead of sending the database to their environment.  We could have them remote into our network perhaps.  What do you think?

Comment: That is something you should discuss internally. It really depends on what you have on that database. If there is nothing that you would flinch at getting leaked to the outside world then maybe it is too cautious. If that database contains the secret identities of CIA operatives around the world then that might not be cautious enough. It all depends....

Comment: It does contain customer personal information, so somewhere in between, but a little closer to the "CIA operatives" level than the other.  We are now in the process of discussing options.

Comment: In that case the approach mentioned by @JeroenMostert is a solid one. You could script the schema and then use that to create a new database. Then copy only the data needed for your new features excluding any PII data (or make some up if they need a sample). Scripting can easily be done from SSMS. The selectively copying data might be more difficult depending on how complex the relationships are.

Answer (score 0):

Your backup can be restored on any SQL Server unless 
- it is encrypted
- they have a lower SQL Server version
- they have a lower SQL Server edition and Enterprise features prevent restoring on a Standard edition. Backup Compression was one of those features back in 2008, afair, and partitioning as well.
- you have large database files that their file system cannot handle.

That's all I can think of. In any case they should get a helpful error message.

Also, some people cannot use a database copy because they lack knowledge. They might try and attach a backup file. They might try and restore a detached mdf file. They might not know how to redirect file paths (restore ... from ... with ..., move 'file' to 'location')